# How to connect with database SQL server

Tags: android, sql-server

I have a task to develop the application, with the help of the SQL server remote database.

I have tables created in the SQL server and I have to develop the application with posting the data to SQL server from mobile. I don't know any type of how it works with SQL server I have work with PHP but I have no idea of SQL server.

So please help me if it possible and send me the sample code so I can develop it in a batter way.

I have an SQL Server database in the remote server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's Java, you'll need JDBC:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/

And here's Microsoft-specific info:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313100